# Take a screenshot in appcelerator and send it by email

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

How do I take a screenshot in appcelerator using a click event and send it using email? I have developed a floating action bar and want to associate a click event with it that takes a screenshot of the current screen and then opens an email dialog.

I tried the following:

```
$.btnScreen.addEventListener("click",function(e){ Ti.Media.takeScreenshot(function(){
```

Comment: Can you post the code you tried ?

Comment: @xiawi I didnt get any code for taking screenshot in appcelerator

Comment: $.btnScreen.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  Ti.Media.takeScreenshot(function(){

Comment: Welcome to SO. I added the code you shared in your comment to your question. You can use the edit function to add more information to your question. This helps keeping all the information in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're calling the right method, but you're not actually capturing the blob. You should do something along these lines: (keep in mind, email dialog doesn't work in simulator)

```
Ti.Media.takeScreenshot(function(blob){
    var dialog = Ti.UI.createEmailDialog();
    dialog.addAttachment(blob.media);
    dialog.open();
});
```

Comment: Thanks , needed further help , I have used the email dialog and when I run the app on phone , it shows me all the apps available to send mail , is it possible to open a particular or two apps , like only Outlook and Gmail should be the only options ?

Comment: nah this is as far as I know out of your hands.